# How to get an xpathContext from an xmlNode in python

Tags: python, xpath, xmlnode

big fan of xpath on .net, and sax in python, but first time using xpath in python.

I have a small script, that uses xpath to select some nodes from a doc, iterates through them, and then ideally uses xpath again to get the relevant data from them. However I can't get that last bit, once I have the xmlNode I cannot get a context from it.

```
import libxml2
import urllib

doc = libxml2.parseDoc(
        urllib.urlopen('http://somemagicwebservice.com/').read())
ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
listitems = ctxt.xpathEval('//List/ListItem')
for item in listitems:
    itemctxt = item.xpathNewContext()
    title = itemctxt.xpathEval('//ItemAttributes/Title')
    asin = itemctxt.xpathEval('//Item/ASIN')
    itemctxc.xpathFreeContext()
ctxt.xpathFreeContext()
doc.freeDoc()
```

However the `itemctxt = item.xpathNewContext()` bit fails with

```
itemctxt = item.xpathNewContext()
AttributeError: xmlNode instance has no attribute 'xpathNewContext'
```

Any ideas how to use xpath on a xmlNode? I can't find any good online info.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think an XPathContext makes sense on an element? Try creating a new XPathContext, and setting it's node to the current element.

That said, I haven't used libxml2 directly, so it's a bit of a wild guess. I typically uses lxml, that exposes an ElementTree API around libxml2 and libxslt. It's much easier to use, and does indeed allow xpath() on elements. Of course, if you already have a lot of code using libxml2 you probably don't want to switch, but in that case you might want to take a look at lxmls source to see how it does it.

http://codespeak.net/svn/lxml/trunk/src/lxml/xpath.pxi

http://codespeak.net/svn/lxml/trunk/src/lxml/_elementpath.py

Seems good starting places.

Comment: Well I had similar problems with lxml, but it turns out the problem was actually related to how xpath deals with namespaces. lxml's ElementPath simplified things a bit. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone wants to see what I ended up with, check out https://bitbucket.org/kurthaeusler/getwishlist/src/tip/getwishlist.py

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379708/288875 suggests to call `setContextNode(..)` on a newly created context:

```
itemctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()

for item in listitems:
    itemctxt.setContextNode(item)
    title = itemctxt.xpathEval('.//ItemAttributes/Title')

    ...

itemctxt.xpathFreeContext()
```

In the version of python libxml (2.9.1) which I'm currently using it turns out that one can even call:

```
item.xpathEval('.//ItemAttributes/Title')
```

Note that you'll have to add a dot at the beginning of the xpath expressions `.//` (instead of `//`), otherwise you'll get search results relative to the document root.