# Python and libxml2: how to iterate in xml nodes with XPATH

Tags: python, xml, xpath, libxml2

I have a problem with retrieving information from a XML tree.

My XML has this shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<records xmlns="http://www.mysyte.com/foo">
  <record>
    <id>first</id>
    <name>john</name>
    <papers>
      <paper>john_1</paper>
      <paper>john_2</paper>
    </papers>
  </record>
  <record>
    <id>second</id>
    <name>mike</name>
    <papers>
      <paper>mike_a</paper>
      <paper>mike_b</paper>
    </papers>
  </record>
  <record>
    <id>third</id>
    <name>albert</name>
    <papers>
      <paper>paper of al</paper>
      <paper>other paper</paper>
    </papers>
  </record>
</records>
```

What I want to do is to extract tuples of data like the follow:

```
[{'code': 'first', 'name': 'john'}, 
 {'code': 'second', 'name': 'mike'}, 
 {'code': 'third', 'name': 'albert'}]
```

Now I wrote this python code:

```
try:
  doc = libxml2.parseDoc(xml)
except (libxml2.parserError, TypeError):
  print "Problems loading XML"

ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
ctxt.xpathRegisterNs("pre", "http://www.mysyte.com/foo")

record_nodes = ctxt.xpathEval('/pre:records/pre:record')

for record_node in record_nodes:
  id = record_node.xpathEval('id')[0].content
  name = record_node.xpathEval('name')[0].content
  ret_list.append({'code': id, 'name': name})
```

My problem is that I don't have any result and I have the impression that I'm doing something wrong with the XPATH when I iterate on the nodes.

I also tried with these XPATHs for the id and the name:

```
/id
/name
/record/id
/record/name
/pre:id
/pre:name
```

and so on, but with any result (BTW if I use the prefix in the sub queries I have an error).

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. Note the `setContextNode()` method:

```
import libxml2

xml = "test.xml"
doc = libxml2.parseFile(xml) 

ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext() 
ctxt.xpathRegisterNs("pre","http://www.mysyte.com/foo") 

ret_list = []
record_nodes = ctxt.xpathEval('/pre:records/pre:record') 

for node in record_nodes:
    ctxt.setContextNode(node)
    _id = ctxt.xpathEval('pre:id')[0].content
    name = ctxt.xpathEval('pre:name')[0].content
    ret_list.append({'code': _id, 'name': name}) 

print ret_list
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to sign this answer as the best one! It actually works in the way I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to switch to [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), here is one way it could be done:

```
import lxml.etree as le
root=le.XML(content)
result=[]
namespaces={'pre':'http://www.mysyte.com/foo'}
for record in root:
    id=record.xpath('pre:id',namespaces=namespaces)[0]
    name=record.xpath('pre:name',namespaces=namespaces)[0]
    result.append({'code':id.text,'name':name.text})
print(result)
# [{'code': 'first', 'name': 'john'}, {'code': 'second', 'name': 'mike'}, {'code': 'third', 'name': 'albert'}]
```

Building off of [Dimitre Novatchev's XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366032/python-and-libxml2-how-to-iterate-in-xml-nodes-with-xpath/3371664#3371664), you could do this:

```
id_name_nodes = iter(ctxt.xpathEval('/pre:records/pre:record/*[self::pre:id or self::pre:name]'))

ret_list=[]
for id,name in zip(id_name_nodes,id_name_nodes):
    ret_list.append({'code':id.content,'name':name.content})
print(ret_list)
```

This libxml2 code, relies on every record having an id and name.
If an `id` or `name` is missing, the `ret_list` will pair the wrong id and name, failing silently. Under the same circumstance, the lxml code would raise an error.

Comment: I'm using libxml2 everywhere and I would like to keep using it also in this case.
However thanks for your answer!

Comment: lxml also uses the `libxml2` library (& `libxslt`). It's basically a layer on top to make tricky things like this easy.

Answer (score 0):

**You can select all the elements you need** with a single XPath expression:

```
/pre:records/pre:record/*[self::pre:id or self::pre:name]
```

Then just process the selected nodes in python.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Giovanni-Di-Milia: This answers the XPath part -- I don't know Python. Having selected all nodes you want, you should be able to process them in Python and to produce the wanted result.

Comment: Does this guarantee any order in which the nodes are returned ? If not, this would add some complication on the python side in order to keep track which `id` belongs to which `name`.

Comment: @Andre-Holzner: All XPath engines I know return the selected modes in document order. And libxml is no exception of this rule.

Answer (score -1):

libxslt lacks such an important namespace support for some reason, but we can pre-parse the xml file, pre-read namespaces from it and then call xsltproc with those namespaces

```
def xpath(xml, xpathexpression):
    f=open(xml)
    fcontent = f.read()
    f.close()

    doc=libxml2.parseFile(xml)
    xp = doc.xpathNewContext()
    for nsdeclaration in re.findall('xmlns:*\w*="[^"]*"', fcontent):
        m = re.match('xmlns:(\w+)=.*', nsdeclaration)
        if m:
            ns = m.group(1)
        else:
            ns = "default"
        url = nsdeclaration[nsdeclaration.find('"')+1:nsdeclaration.rfind('"')]
        xp.xpathRegisterNs(ns, url)
    a=xp.xpathEval(xpathexpression)
    if len(a):
        return a[0].content
    return ""
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the questions or adds something more to what already written